# _ does not show up in Spyder variable explorer

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Is there a way to also see _ (result of the last executed expression/statement) in the Spyder variable explorer?

Comment: `_`is usually an template for an variable you don't want to use.

Comment: @Vala.D. Why not? I would like to be able to see it from the variable explorer. In matlab "ans" is exposed in the variable explorer and this can be sometimes useful...

Comment: @Chicken What Vala. D was referring to was the fact that by convention `_` is used to denote an unused argument. There's nothing stopping you from using it as a name of a variable.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik I do not want to name a variable _. I just wanna see it in the Spyder variable explorer like all other variables. This is a Spyder question I guess, not a Python one.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To do that, you need to go the Options (i.e. hamburger) menu of the Variable Explorer and deactivate the option called `Exclude private references`:

[image: Option in variable explorer]

Comment: Thank you this works, but shows dozens of additional variables which i dont need. Ideally I would like to add only _ and no other variables... Would that be possible?

Comment: Sorry, that's the best we can do.

Comment: Ok I guess this might be a very simple patch that for some reason you are not happy to make. Np with that. It would still be very helpful if you could somehow point to me more or less what "area" in the source code of spyder (which I can find on github) i should be changing (locally) in order to get the desired behavior. Maybe (maybe) I would be able to change the code locally by myself and solve my problem. By doing so I could start getting a bit involved in the development of spyder, which is to me the best python ide...

Comment: Having said that, I am quite dumb as a coder, so do not ever expect me to do anything non trivial in the Spyder code base :(

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba: Are there intentions to enhance Spyder to automatically show all variables in the explorer without having to debug to see them?

Comment: @user9106985, I don't understand what you mean by this: variables in the Variable Explorer when you are not debugging too.